# How to use Selenium server standalone to test https web applications?

Tags: security, testing, selenium, https, automated-tests

In our web application project, I used to use **Selenium Server Standalone** to test the website. Then we switched from **http** to **https** and now none of the test cases work anymore! When I run the test cases. the Google Chrome opens but says

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from ...
```

Should I add any new flag to my test suites in order for Selenium Server Standalone to be able to run through https ? 
Any other suggestion for solving this issue?!

Answer (score -1):

Are you using selenium WebDriver? By Selenium Server Standalone I guess not...

So in WebDriver Chrome and FF browsers come with the driver it self and this issue is resolved there. I'm using it and don't see this page at all.

My suggestion is to migrate to it.